# Clique POA Signed recently must wait for others

Tags: poa, geth-clique

In poa private ethereum network I have 2 nodes i mentioned the 1st node as a validator in genesis file after sometimes I'm adding the second account as a validator or signer in geth console using clique.propose to add the 2nd node as validator. When i check the clique.getSigners() 1st and 2nd node are in signers list Now i have 2 account as signer When i try to make a transaction from 1st to 2nd account or 2nd to 1st account the tx was not happened All tha tx was in pending state and both can see each other as peer (verify using admin.peers). When I started to mine for both nodes using the code below, both nodes stuck at Signed recently, must wait for others
Check signers - clique.getSigners - both of the account appear

Check peers for both node - admin.peers - both are okay

Then both mine using below code

```
geth personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)

geth eth.defaultAccount = eth.coinbase

geth miner.start()
```

**Geth version 1.9.14**

Answer (score 1):

if you use bootnode param --bootnodes while starting of network it will work
https://coinsbench.com/create-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-network-829be72658a5